# TextView Background Resource

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, image

I implemented the following TextView in a RelativeView:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"/>
```

The problem is that the size will be set dynamically to 15% of the screen while the application is running. But when I do this the background ressource doesn't get the size of the TextView. It has the original size of `150x150 px`. What can I do to avoid this?

(I don't want to take a smaller ressource because it doesn't look well then)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using another `scaleType`, for example `android:scaleType="fitXY"`.

Also you can try making a nine-patch image. To do this, go to your Android SDK folder - tools - draw9patch application. Then you will have options to open your image and then save it as nine-patch image. Reference it as usual in your layout.

Comment: Did you try creating a 9-patch image like he said? A 9-patch is exactly what you need

Comment: Did you open te image file and saved it with the same name without changing? Also delete the old image from the drawable folder.

Comment: I used the 9patch editor but now I have a black stripe next to my picture and the picture is still not scaled. Where could be my mistake?

Comment: Could the "wrapcontent" field be the reason why it's not scaled?

Comment: Can you post a link to a screenshot?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know a good place to upload. I can describe it. The TextView itself is 150x150px big although I coded something different

Comment: Why must you use wrap_content and not a absolute size in dip? Or set the size dynamically according to screen size for example?